# Flutter :[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8

I have this error and i can't understand where is my mistake

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception:
> NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'output' was called on null. E/flutter
> (16491): Receiver: null E/flutter (16491): Tried calling: output

the error refer to this function but i have no error syntax on it

```
import 'dart:convert';
BluetoothConnection connection;

void _sendOnMessageToBluetooth() async {
    connection.output.add(utf8.encode("1" + "\r\n"));
    await connection.output.allSent;
    setState(() {
      deviceState = 1;
    });
  }
```

and this is where i'am calling it

```
FlatButton(
onPressed: _sendOnMessageToBluetooth ==null? "": _sendOnMessageToBluetooth,
child:Text("ON",
style:TextStyle(color:Colors.red[400]),,),
```

can any one help !

Comment: What is the `connection` variable? Where is it initialized in the code?

Comment: there is  BluetoothConnection connection;

Comment: Edit the question to include that part too.

Comment: okay i will do that now thanks for your hint

Comment: So from the code that you have shared so far, it seems like you have only declared the variable `connection` and not initialized it. Have you assigned an instance of `BluetoothConnection` to it anywhere in the code? Something like `connection = BluetoothConnection()` ?

Comment: no , i'am not do this  connection = BluetoothConnection() , where should i add this line and in which is will use ?

Comment: No, you should not add this exact line. It was only for example. The point is that you need to assign an instance of `BluetoothConnection` to it before you can call methods/getters on it.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that because i don't know , please !

Comment: See the **usage** section on this link - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial It might help.

Comment: sorry , but i did it before and didn't help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the 'connection' variable without first initializing or assigning it to something. Hence when called 'connection.output', it is causing an error. Try to find where the 'connection' variable is initialized and use from there or take it as a parameter to function.
This might work:

```
void _sendOnMessageToBluetooth() async {
    BluetoothConnection connection = new BluetoothConnection();
    connection.output.add(utf8.encode("1" + "\r\n"));
    await connection.output.allSent;
    setState(() {
      deviceState = 1;
    });
  }
```

Comment: i'm initialize it before using it
BluetoothConnection connection;